# Y vs X with spatial variation

Tags: regression, spatial

I am trying to learn a relationship between two variables Y and X, X is the independent variable. The nature of the relationship is quadratic, from some domain experience, but the relationship itself changes in space (coordinates). I have data from some experiments, Y(xi,yi), and X(xi,yi). What may be a statistically robust way to learn the true relationship? I looked into this method called GWR or geographically weighted regression, but I also read that its not very stable and fraught with problems of bias and such. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your [accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123027/r-geographically-weighted-regression-gwmodel/123031#123031).